# Assign unique ID's to three tables in SELECT query, ID's should not overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on SQL Sever and I want to assign unique Id's to rows being pulled from those three tables, but the id's should not overlap.

Let's say, Table one contains cars data, table two contains house data, table three contains city data. I want to pull all this data into a single table with a unique id to each of them say cars from 1-100, house from 101 - 200 and city from 300- 400.

How can I achieve this using only select queries. I can't use insert statements.

To be more precise, 
I have one table with computer systems/servers host information which has id from 500-700. 
I have another tables, storage devices (id's from 200-600) and routers (ids from 700-900). I have already collected systems data. Now I want to pull storage systems and routers data in such a way that the consolidated data at my end should has a unique id for all records. This needs to be done only by using SELECT queries.

I was using SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS UniqueID and storing it in temp tables (separate for storage and routers). But I believe that this may lead to some overlapping. Please suggest any other way to do this.

```
 An extension to this question:

Creating consistent integer from a string: 

All I have is various strings like this  
 String1
 String2Hello123 
 String3HelloHowAreYou             


I Need to convert them in to positive integers say some thing like     
String1 = 12 
String2Hello123 = 25 
String3HelloHowAreYou = 4567


Note that I am not expecting the numbers in any order.Only requirement is number generated for one string should not conflict with other

Now later after the reboot If I do not have 2nd string instead there is a new string

        String1 = 12    
        String3HelloHowAreYou = 4567    
        String2Hello123HowAreyou = 28    

Not that the number 25 generated for 2nd string earlier can not be sued for the new string.

Using extra storage (temp tables) is not allowed
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data that would be in these tables, and what the expected output would be from the select query?

Comment: To be more precise, I have one table with computer systems/servers host information which has id from 500-700. I have another tables, storage devices (id's from 200-600) and routers (ids from 700-900). I have already collected systems data. Now I want to pull storage systems and routers data in such a way that the consolidated data at my end should has a unique id for all records. This needs to be done only by using SELECT queries.

I was using SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)) AS UniqueID and storing it in temp tables (separate for storage and routers).

Answer (score 2):

if you dont care where the data comes from:

```
with dat as (
select 't1' src, id from table1 
union all 
select 't2' src, id  from table2
union all 
select 't3' src, id  from table3
)
select *
     , id2 = row_number() over( order by _some_column_ )
from dat
```

Comment: It is good to note that this will work if the 3 tables have the same amount of columns and are structured the same, else the UNION will fail.

Comment: @A ツ I know, I'm just talking about the UNION queries within your WITH table expression